# OneNote's PagesUrl Not Including All Pages in a Section

Tags: python, api, get, onenote, onenote-api

I want to get a list of all the pages in a given section for a given notebook. I have the id for the section I want and use it in a GET call to obtain a dictionary of the section's information. One of the keys in the dictionary is "pagesUrl". A GET call on this returns a list of dictionaries where there's one dictionary for each page in this section.

Up until yesterday, this worked perfectly. However, as of today, pagesUrl only returns pages created within the last minute or so. Anything older isn't seen. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday (2016/04/08) there was an incident with the OneNote API which prevented us from updating the list of pages. This was resolved rpughly at 11PM PST and the API should be returning all pages now.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you very much for letting me know :)